# Getting average price across stores and across months

Tags: sas

I am trying to use the proc tabulate procedure to arrive at the average price of some configurable items, across stores and across months. Below is the sample data set, which I need to process

```
Configuration|Store_Postcode|Retail Price|month
163|SE1 2BN|455|1
320|SW12 9HD|545|1
23|E2 0RY|515|1
```

The below code is displaying the month wise average price for each configuration.

```
proc tabulate data=cs2.pos_data_raw;
    class configuration store_postcode month;
    var retail_price;
    table configuration,month*MEAN*retail_price;
run;
```

But can I get this grouped one more level - at the Store Post code level? I modified the code to read as shown below, but executing this is crashing the system!

```
proc tabulate data=cs2.pos_data_raw;
    class configuration store_postcode month;
    var retail_price;
    table configuration,store_postcode*month*MEAN*retail_price;
run;
```

Please advice if my approach is incorrect, or what am I doing wrong in proc tabulate so much so that it crashes the system.

Comment: Does the SAS session just disappear ? Does the whole computer crash (unlikely) ? If there are error messages in the log you can capture, show them.  How many rows in the data ?  Is cs2 a remote library reference ? What is the ODS destination (html, pdf, excel, other) ?  how many rows in data overall ? what is the row dimension cardinality (how many different configuration) and column dimension cardinality (how many different postcode*month) ?  My guess is a tremendously large column dimension combined with the ods destination is causing the issue.

Comment: You can troubleshoot for a data / ods issue by using cs2.pos_data_raw(obs=####) and do runs for #### 1, 10, 100, 1000, etc until crash occurs.  You might also want to do any of in any combination A) swap the dimensions (put configuration on rhs of comma), B) use a page dimension, C) use by statement, D) use a where statement

Comment: Given that there are a lot of PostalCodes you're likely crashing the output. I would suggest possibly pre-summarizing the data using PROC MEANS and then using PROC REPORT to display it. Separating the calculation from the display may help.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this exactly answers your question since I am new to SAS, but when I switched `store_postcode*month*MEAN*retail_price` to `month*store_postcode*MEAN*retail_price` , it worked without crashing. I am just guessing that the reason for this is because your data only contains 1 value for month and multiple for postal code, therefore month is the most general level of categorization then it becomes more specific.

On a side note, I tried to format the table in another way also to segment the data by postal code:

```
proc tabulate data=pos_data_raw;
class configuration store_postcode month;
var retail_price;
table store_postcode*configuration, month*MEAN*retail_price;
run;
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

where the table will have postal code and configuration id on the left and month and retail price on top.